# Difference Between Dates Issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, date

I am having an issue of getting the difference in days between two dates. I will post my code below, but what I am trying to achieve is very simple, just get the difference between 2 dates in days and place the difference in a label.

Code:

```
 string date1 = "";
 string date2 = "";
 if (myRdr.HasRows)
        {
            myRdr.Read();
            date1 = myRdr["Date 1"].ToString();
            date2 = myRdr["Date 2"].ToString();
        }
```

`Date 1` and `Date 2` are what I am selecting from a query for SQL Server. The date format that I am pulling from my table is `12/25/2015`

I have tried these lines to convert the string to date, but it returns nothing:

```
DateTime date1Diff= DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
DateTime date2Diff= DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Then I was planning on getting the difference between `date2Diff - date1Diff`

So my question is, why are `date1Diff` and `date2Diff` returning nothing and what is the best way to get the difference between those two dates?

Comment: Compare used date formats ;)

Comment: Haha what what? You say you have data in format `dd-MM-yyyy`, yet you pass into the function format `dd/MM/yyyy` instead... Plus, I don't really understand why you store your dates as string. You're creating unnecessary problems for yourself like this.

Comment: Why are you making you reader output strings instead of casting directly to a DateTime?

Comment: What is the data type in the SQL database? Ideally, you shouldn't be dealing with text formats at all...

Comment: Was a typo on my part, fixed now

Comment: @JonSkeet they are datetime, I am converting them to the format above when I select them in the select statement

Comment: *Why* though? Why would you want them as strings rather than keeping them as `DateTime`? If you wanted to add two integers together, would you convert those to strings as well?

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy` cannot convert `12/25/2015`, you need `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: @walther you forgot your question in your question is why I didn't answer your question, "what what" isn't asking a question "why"

Comment: @codeBoy.. as already suggested, do not convert your date to a string. Leave it as a date and then format doesn't matter and you can use date functions.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid that is what I ended up doing, thank you

Comment: So why have you accepted an answer which doesn't do what you ended up doing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    Put this method in class form or in the same form pass the string date format that you read it gives you date difference

    public static double GetDateDiff(string d1, string d2)
    {
        double result = 0.0;
        DateTime MyDate1 = Convert.ToDateTime(d1);
        DateTime MyDate2 = Convert.ToDateTime(d2);
        result = ((MyDate1 - MyDate2).TotalDays);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. Converting between `DateTime` and string unnecessarily introduces lots of room for broken conversions - especially when just using `Convert.ToDateTime` instead of specifying the exact expected format. For dates such as "06/05/2015" it would be *really* easy to end up breaking things.

Comment: This is solution if data is in form of string, and format is another question. My answer does not concern date format. OP asked take difference of two dates in string format.

Comment: But "06/05/2015" can represent two different dates - so which would you expect this to return? Fundamentally the OP shouldn't be converting the `DateTime` values into strings in the first place - converting them back again afterwards isn't the right approach here; the right approach is to *remove* a conversion rather than adding one.